# how to give a grid row a row command

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I want to make my gridview rows selectable. I don't like the idea of a user clicking a button or link on the grid to select the row. How can I give the actual row a row command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how you do it.**

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView GridView1 = (GridView)frmViewClaimantPE.FindControl("GridView1");
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);

    }

}
```